# Compute (Z4 * Z6) / <(0,2)>

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Fraleigh's A first course in abstract algebra, for example problem,

Compute (Z4 * Z6) / <(0,2)>.

These are my process.

Let H=<(0,2)> = {(0,2), (0,4), (0,0)}

Then

(0,0)+H = H
(1,0)+H = {(1,2),(1,4),(1,0)}
(2,0)+H = {(2,2),(2,4),(2,0)}
(3,0)+H = {(3,2),(3,4),(3,0)}
(0,1)+H = {(0,3),(0,5),(0,1)}
(0,3)+H = {(0,5),(0,1),(0,3)}
(0,5)+H = {(0,1),(0,3),(0,5)}

So there cosets are (0,0) (1,0) (2,0) (3,0) (0,1)

So (Z4 * Z6) / <(0,2)> is isomorphic to Z4*Z2

But here's the statement is the books.

*Here the first factor of Z4 of Z4*Z6 is left alone. The Z6 factor, on the other hand is essentially collapsed by a subgroup of order 3, giving a factor group in the second factor of order 2 that must be isomorphic to Z2.*

I can’t understand this statement that what ‘collapsed’ mean in this statement though I read previous part. Also what ‘left alone’ means.

And are there any easy way to understand 'coset', 'factor group(quotient group)' ?

Comment: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190034/why-is-mathbbz-4-times-mathbbz-6-langle-0-2-rangle-isomorphic-to-m?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518572/calculate-the-factor-group-mathbbz-4-times-mathbbz-6-langle0-2-ran?rq=1)